# Boolean operation to obtain volume

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, boolean-computation

Imagine a sphere with $R40$ centered at ${0,0,0}$.

Now a cylinder with $R25$ tangent in one of the quadrants of the sphere ending on the surface of the sphere.

How do I get the volume of the resulting solid?

```
r1 = 40; r2 = 25;
Graphics[{ Circle[{0, 0}, r1], Line[{{r1, r2}, {r1, -r2}}], Line[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], r2}, {r1, r2}}], Line[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], -r2}, {r1, -r2}}] }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
r1 = 40; r2 = 25;
R = RegionUnion[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], 
   Cylinder[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], 0, 0}, {r1, 0, 0}}, r2]];
R // Volume
```

> 250/3 (812 + 39 Sqrt[39]) π

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Red, Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1]}, {Opacity[0.5], 
   Blue, Cylinder[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], 0, 0}, {r1, 0, 0}}, r2]}}]
```

[image]

Volume of the blue solid:

```
Volume[R] - Volume[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1]]
```

> -(53000 π/3) + 3250 Sqrt[39] π

using [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) also returns the same result:

```
R = RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1], 
   Cylinder[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], 0, 0}, {r1, 0, 0}}, r2]];
Volume[Cylinder[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], 0, 0}, {r1, 0, 0}}, r2]] - Volume[R]
```

Comment: Could you add the information on the volume of the blue solid? I know it would subtract the volume from the sphere, but there may be a more effective method.

Comment: @LCarvalho I think subtracting the sphere volume is the best method because we have that result already calculated. Another method can be to subtract intersection volume of the solids from the volume of cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

```
r1 = 40; r2 = 25;

rgns = {Ball[{0, 0, 0}, r1],
   Cylinder[{{Sqrt[r1^2 - r2^2], 0, 0}, {r1, 0, 0}}, r2]};
```

[`Ball`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ball.html) and [`Cylinder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cylinder.html) are regions

```
RegionQ /@ rgns

(*  {True, True}  *)

Volume[RegionUnion @@ rgns] // FullSimplify

(*  250/3 (812 + 39 Sqrt[39]) π  *)
```

Verifying with alternate approaches

```
Total[Volume /@ rgns] - Volume[RegionIntersection @@ rgns] // Simplify

(*  250/3 (812 + 39 Sqrt[39]) π  *)

Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ (RegionUnion @@ rgns)] // FullSimplify

(*  250/3 (812 + 39 Sqrt[39]) π  *)

Graphics3D[rgns]
```

[image]